# Plotly graph aspect ratio and annotation size

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

this is in regards to the automated aspect ratio of a plotly graphs which then distorts the annotations when the widow size is changed.

here is the relevant code:

```
fig.update_layout(
autosize=True,
#width=1000,
#height=500,
annotations=[
    dict(text="Coin:",xref="paper", yref="paper", x=0.85, y=1.063, xanchor='right', yanchor='top',
          showarrow=False, font=dict(family='Arial', size=20)),
    dict(text="Scale:", x=0.935, xref="paper", y=1.063, yref="paper", xanchor='right', yanchor='top',
          showarrow=False, font=dict(family='Arial', size=20)),
    dict(text="Time Frame", x=0, xref="paper", y=1.08,yref="paper", xanchor='right', yanchor='top', 
          showarrow=False, font=dict(family='Arial', size=20))        
    
])
```

I've figured out by anchoring I can set a point of reference which then uses x and y as a percentage of the graph aspect ratio, however, I can't figure out how to resize the text so its not all merged together or far apart when I change the web window size.

failing your help I could try a drop down which would set the value for the graph aspect size and from there create a calculation which would reduce the text size value accordingly. I would like to avoid this because its rather tedious for a user to change every time.

[image: Full screen window]

[image: small window]